# CSS3 animation not playing when div is clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an animation in CSS3 that I'm trying to play when a certain element is clicked using Javascript.  The animation is called in a CSS class, and when the element is clicked, Javascript gives the desired element the class.  This is working, but the animation isn't playing, can anyone explain why?

**CSS**

```
@keyframes growPage{
    from{color: white;}
    to{color: black;}
}

.grow{
    animation-name growPage;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

**JS**

```
let pageLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("pagelink");
for(let i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; i++){
    pageLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        let page = document.getElementById(this.id +"_page");
        if(page.classList.contains("page")){
            switch(page.id){
                case "aboutme_page":
                    page.classList.add("grow");
                    console.log(page);
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="home" class="page active row">
    <article id="aboutme" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="portfolio" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="services" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="whyme" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="feedback" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="contactme" class="pagelink col-lg-4">
        <div class="holder">
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
<section id="aboutme_page" class="page row">
    <article class="col-lg-9"><article>
</section>
```

Comment: animation-name growPage; <- it's lacking a : (colon)

Comment: ^^ and `<article class="col-lg-9"><article>` article isn't closed. `</article>`.

Comment: @EladKatz wow, I didn't even notice, thank you.